# An error occured during the Network Policy Server use of Extensible Authentication Protocol

Tags: radius, nps

It has been almost two weeks to get my radius server up and running. I think i have run in almost to all the issue known to Radius :).

Am guessing this to be a Certificate issue, Please go through the radius dump from the switch below. The error am getting is "Event ID L 6273" "Reason Code: 23" "An error occured during the Network Policy Server use of Extensible Authentication Protocol (EAP). Check EAP log files for EAP errors."

```
EAP IPC From 802.1x to RADIUS.
Adding EAP request Object.
EAP Req Id: 238.
Sock Index = 5, Sock Descr = 79 - In RAD.
Dump EAP Pkt - radF10AuthEapRequest.
EAP Code: EAP Response Packet, Id: 17, EAP Type: EAP Identity
EAP Pkt Len: 25.
EAP Dump.
---------.

2 11 0 19 1 63 68 6e 6c 61 62 5c 73 75 64 68 61 72 73 68 
61 6e 5f 73 0 
RAD:EAP Thread, SETUP_REQUEST state.
Count = 3, Intvl = 5.
Supplicant's Mac Addr: 00.80.64.c5.8c.dd
User Name:chnlab\sudharshan_s
User Name Len:19
State Attrib Len saved up - 0.
Number of EAP attributes = 1, EAP Len = 25.
RAD Req Id: 238.
Msg Auth Offset 85.
RADIUS Packet Dump.
-------------------
RAD Pkt Len = 123.

1 ee 0 7b 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
4 6 a 10 d4 80 3d 6 0 0 0 f 5 6 0 0 0 2e 1f 13 
30 30 2d 38 30 2d 36 34 2d 43 35 2d 38 43 2d 44 44 1 15 63 
68 6e 6c 61 62 5c 73 75 64 68 61 72 73 68 61 6e 5f 73 4f 1b 
2 11 0 19 1 63 68 6e 6c 61 62 5c 73 75 64 68 61 72 73 68 
61 6e 5f 73 0 50 12 81 72 64 60 95 4 e1 8a c7 76 27 a0 aa 
12 c0 8b 
RAD:EAP Thread, REQUEST_READY state.
RAD:EAP Thread, SETUP_REQUEST state.
Count = 3, Intvl = 5.
Supplicant's Mac Addr: 00.80.64.c5.8c.dd
User Name:chnlab\sudharshan_s
User Name Len:19
Setting up State Attrib, EAP Type - 25.
Number of EAP attributes = 1, EAP Len = 17.
RAD Req Id: 241.
Msg Auth Offset 115.
RADIUS Packet Dump.
-------------------
RAD Pkt Len = 153.

1 f1 0 99 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 01d1h13m : RADIUS_EAP: Try server 10.16.212.111:1812 for id 238
1d1h13m : RADIUS: Initial Transmit id 238, code 1, len 123, Access-Request 
1d1h13m :   Attribute  4    length  4   NAS IP Address : 10.16.212.128
1d1h13m :   Attribute 61    length  4   NAS Port type : 15
1d1h13m :   Attribute  5    length  4   NAS Port : 46
1d1h13m :   Attribute 31    length 17   Calling-station-id : 00-80-64-C5-8C-DD 
1d1h13m :   Attribute  1    length 19   User Name : chnlab\sudharshan_s
1d1h13m :   Attribute 79    length 25   Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 80    length 16   Unknown : 
1d1h13m : RADIUS: Received from id 238, code 11, Access-Challenge 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 27    length  4   Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 79    length  6   Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 24    length 36   Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 80    length 16   Unknown : 
1d1h13m : RADIUS_EAP: Try server 10.16.212.111:1812 for id 239
1d1h13m : RADIUS: Initial Transmit id 239, code 1, len 224, Access-Request 
1d1h13m :   Attribute  4    length  4   NAS IP Address : 10.16.212.128
1d1h13m :   Attribute 61    length  4   NAS Port type : 15
1d1h13m :   Attribute  5    length  4   NAS Port : 46
1d1h13m :   Attribute 31    length 17   Calling-station-id : 00-80-64-C5-8C-DD 
1d1h13m :   Attribute  1    length 19   User Name : chnlab\sudharshan_s
1d1h13m :   Attribute 24    length 36   Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 79    length 88   Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 80    length 16   Unknown : 
1d1h13m : RADIUS: Received from id 239, code 11, Access-Challenge 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 27    length  4   Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 79    length 253  Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 79    length 253  Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 79    length 253  Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 79    length 253  Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 79    length 253  Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 79    length 231  Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 24    length 36   Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 80    length 16   Unknown : 
1d1h13m : RADIUS_EAP: Try server 10.16.212.111:1812 for id 240
1d1h13m : RADIUS: Initial Transmit id 240, code 1, len 142, Access-Request 
1d1h13m :   Attribute  4    length  4   NAS IP Address : 10.16.212.128
1d1h13m :   Attribute 61    length  4   NAS Port type : 15
1d1h13m :   Attribute  5    length  4   NAS Port : 46
1d1h13m :   Attribute 31    length 17   Calling-station-id : 00-80-64-C5-8C-DD 
1d1h13m :   Attribute  1    length 19   User Name : chnlab\sudharshan_s
1d1h13m :   Attribute 24    length 36   Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 79    length  6   Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 80    length 16   Unknown : 
1d1h13m : RADIUS: Received from id 240, code 11, Access-Challenge 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 27    length  4   Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 79    length 253  Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 79    length 253  Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 79    length 253  Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 79    length 253  Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 79    length 253  Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 79    length  5   Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 24    length 36   Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 80    length 16   Unknown : 
1d1h13m : RADIUS_EAP: Try server 10.16.212.111:1812 for id 241
1d1h13m : RADIUS: Initial Transmit id 241, code 1, len 153, Access-Request 
1d1h13m :   Attribute  4    length  4   NAS IP Address : 10.16.212.128
1d1h13m :   Attribute 61    length  4   NAS Port type : 15
1d1h13m :   Attribute  5    length  4   NAS Port : 46
1d1h13m :   Attribute 31    length 17   Calling-station-id : 00-80-64-C5-8C-DD 
1d1h13m :   Attribute  1    length 19   User Name : chnlab\sudharshan_s
1d1h13m :   Attribute 24    length 36   Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 79    length 17   Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 80    length 16   Unknown : 
1d1h13m : RADIUS: Received from id 241, code 3, Access-Reject 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 79    length  4   Unknown : 
1d1h13m :   Attribute 80    length 16   Unknown :
```

Comment: You should do what is suggested and "Check EAP log files for EAP errors." Add such logs to your post.

Comment: Where would i find those logs, /system32/logfiles does not have it.

Comment: Tucked under Event Viewer perhaps? Sorry, I don't know.